# Comparing a String after reading it from Serial fails

Tags: c++, string

I have bought an Arduino starter kit online. Everything seem to work, but when I try for example to use `if`s (and other conditional statements), the LEDs do not turn on. Here is the code for a little project I am currently working on:

```cpp
int redpin = 3;
int greenpin = 2;
int bluepin = 4;
String color;
String msg = "Insert color: ";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(redpin,OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(greenpin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(bluepin,OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(msg);
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  color = Serial.readString();

  if (color == "red") {
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluepin, LOW);
  } 
  if (color == "green") {
    digitalWrite(greenpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluepin, LOW);
  }
  if (color == "blue") {
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluepin, HIGH);
  }

  if (color == "off") {
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluepin, LOW);  
  }
}
```

I tried turning on the RGB LED with single `digitalWrite()` functions and it works. I think that the `if` statements in the code are the problem.

I`m using an Arduino Mega 2560 BTW.

Comment: You should print the variable `color` out to the Serial monitor, to make sure, that you really received, what you send. Also you shouldn't use `Serial.readString()`, but `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` and set your Serial Monitor to a line ending of newline only. Then try again. If that works, I will formulate an answer around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `color = Serial.readString();` `color` also contains a newline character.

You can remove that by adding the line `color.trim();`, or even better, avoid the newline altogether by using `Serial.readStringUntil('\n');` which discards the terminating newline character.

Also, you could, and maybe should, avoid using the `String` class and use:

```cpp
char color[10]; // char array as buffer for reading from Serial
```

```cpp
int number = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', color, 10); //Read input and length
color[number] = '\0'; //Terminate the string by adding '\0' at its end
```

```cpp
if (strcmp(color, "red") == 0) //Use strcmp(), not ==
```

respectively.