# Find OK or ERROR in serial string

Tags: serial, softwareserial, string, serial-data

I am trying to figure out how to capture the `OK` or the `ERROR` from a SIM800l.

I have tried

```
mySerial.println("AT");
while (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
String str = mySerial.readString();
Serial.println(str);
     if (str.equals("OK")) {
        Serial.println("ok");
     } else {
        Serial.println("unknown");
     }
   }
```

But I always getting nothing back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing a String after reading it from Serial fails](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79716/comparing-a-string-after-reading-it-from-serial-fails). The issue is that the string read from the serial port also contains a closing "newline" character so the comparison fails. You need to strip off the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.indexOf` to find characters in a String. It returns a `-1` if a match is not found. See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/indexof/

```cpp
mySerial.println("AT");
String str;

while (mySerial.available() > 0 ) 
{
    str = mySerial.readString();
    Serial.println(str);

    if (str.indexOf("OK") != -1) 
    {
        Serial.println("ok");
    } else if (str.indexOf("ERROR") != -1) 
    {
        Serial.println("error!");
    } else {
        Serial.println("unknown");
    }
}
```